# Drawer.Navigator add image inside it , React native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add an image on the top of the Drawer Navigation, any suggestions on how to do that?

I tried to add the drawer icon function but it is not what I want( and not working), also I see other people use DrawerContentScrollView, but saying missing "SafeAreaProvider" at the top of my app.

App.js

```
  const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <DrawerNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
export default App;
```

DrawerNavigator.js

```
import HomeStackNavigator from "../navigations/Navigator";
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
    const DrawerNavigator = () => {
      return (
        <Drawer.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Home"
          drawerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: "#EEEEEE",
            width: 240,
          }}
          drawerContent={(props) => (
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
              <DrawerItem
                label="SPECIAL BUTTON"
                onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Home")}
              />
              <DrawerItemList {...props} />
            </DrawerContentScrollView>
          )}
        >
          <Drawer.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeStackNavigator}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: "",
              drawerIcon: () => (
                <Image
                  source={require("../Interface_icons/56-Social-Profile/48w/social-profile-avatar.png")}
                  style={{ height: 20, width: 20 }}
                />
              ),
            }}
          />
          <Drawer.Screen name="News" component={News} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="AboutUs" component={AboutUs} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      );
    };
    export default DrawerNavigator;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but saying missing "SafeAreaProvider" at the top of my app

Wrap your app in `SafeAreaProvider`.

```js
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <DrawerNavigator />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
};
export default App;
```